# meaning of "1" in monkey command

Tags: android, command-line, monkey, adb

I recently read a book about android.In that book for running the monkey script the bellow command introduced:

```
adb shell monkey -f myscript.txt 1
```

I searched this command and find out what f meaning. but when I searched about "1", I can not find anything about it. what does this "1" meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root@droid:/ # monkey
monkey
usage: monkey [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE] ...]
          [-c MAIN_CATEGORY [-c MAIN_CATEGORY] ...]
          [--ignore-crashes] [--ignore-timeouts]
          [--ignore-security-exceptions]
          [--monitor-native-crashes] [--ignore-native-crashes]
          [--kill-process-after-error] [--hprof]
          [--pct-touch PERCENT] [--pct-motion PERCENT]
          [--pct-trackball PERCENT] [--pct-syskeys PERCENT]
          [--pct-nav PERCENT] [--pct-majornav PERCENT]
          [--pct-appswitch PERCENT] [--pct-flip PERCENT]
          [--pct-anyevent PERCENT] [--pct-pinchzoom PERCENT]
          [--pkg-blacklist-file PACKAGE_BLACKLIST_FILE]
          [--pkg-whitelist-file PACKAGE_WHITELIST_FILE]
          [--wait-dbg] [--dbg-no-events]
          [--setup scriptfile] [-f scriptfile [-f scriptfile] ...]
          [--port port]
          [-s SEED] [-v [-v] ...]
          [--throttle MILLISEC] [--randomize-throttle]
          [--profile-wait MILLISEC]
          [--device-sleep-time MILLISEC]
          [--randomize-script]
          [--script-log]
          [--bugreport]
          [--periodic-bugreport]
          COUNT
```

`1` is the `COUNT`. Meaning that only 1 "random" command will be executed. The first command that `monkey` runs is starting of the default activity. This trick is being used for starting an app by providing only the package name without having to specify the exact activity name.

Comment: Thanks, for your perfect answer.